# Change UILabel text in UIScrollView

Tags: ios5, uiscrollview, uilabel, paging

I'm trying to make an app in which there's a scrollview with frame and content size set from storyboard. i have inserted a label and both scrollview and uilabel have iboutlet created.
i want to change text of uilabel each time i scroll with paging. content is saved in a nsmutable array as string. there's only single uilabel, and i wanna reuse it with content from array in every page of scroll view. please help..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use one of the method of `UIScrollViewDelegate` like `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` in this you can change the text of label and also the frame of the label to show it in visible rect of scrollview

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)ascrollView
{

    if(lastContentOffset < ascrollView.contentOffset.x)
    {
        if(index-2 >= 0)
        {
            [ascrollView addSubview:[thumbs objectAtIndex:index-2]];
            index-=1;
            //change label text using the index and also it's frame's origin.x
            NSLog(@"Direction Right Index %d",index);
        }
    }
    else if(lastContentOffset > ascrollView.contentOffset.x)
    {
        if(index+2 < [thumbs count])
        {
            [ascrollView addSubview:[thumbs objectAtIndex:index+2]];
            index+=1;
             //change label text using the index and also it's frame's origin.x
            NSLog(@"Direction Left Index %d",index);
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"ScrollViewDidScroll is called");
    lastContentOffset = ascrollView.contentOffset.x;
}
```

here the `lastContentOffset` is float variable which holds the current visible frame's x of the scrollview

in .m file declare two ivars below all the @synthesize as

`NSMutableArray *arr;` & `float lastContentOffset;`

then when you fill your scrollView just assign it's frame's origin.x to the `lastContentOffset` and then use the `arr` to change the text of label

Comment: can you please show me an example what to write in scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:?

Comment: ok will update my answer with some code example wait till then

Comment: see my edited answer and let me now if there is any further needs

Comment: well.. it didnt help. :( too confused. im new to programming.

Comment: where to declare lastContentOffset, it showing me errors.. and problem is i have saved label text in another instance method so i cant access thumbs like that. is there any way to make it work right in that instance?

Comment: ok then i provide you full code in next edit wait and sorry for delay as some network error

Comment: i think i should explain exactly what i need.. im having a horizontal scroll view whose content size is according to array count, this array holds label content. now i have arranged everything in storyboard, ui label displays only last object, and it doesnt repeat in other pages of scroll view.

Comment: just do this `label.frame.origine.x = scrollview.frame.size.width*index;` and for first time assign index with 1.

Comment: then in delegate method just put above line to change labels frame and just change it's text with `[arr objectAtIndex:index];` here `index` is integer

Comment: ok please put some code where you assign or fill your nsmutablearray as you said it is in some instance method, right so it is in coding just make it global to the whole file by putting it as i said below the @synthesize lines

Comment: for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
                    scrollView1.contentSize = CGSizeMake(768.0 * i, scrollView1.frame.size.height);
                    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0 * i, 0.0, scrollView1.frame.size.width, scrollView1.frame.size.height);
                    UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
                    //thumbLabelGreen1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 100.0, 20.0)];
                    thumbLabelGreen1.text = [NSString stringWithString:@"Hello"];

Comment: [subView addSubview:thumbLabelGreen1];
                    [self.scrollView1 addSubview:subView];
                }

Comment: as you assign the subView's frame's origin.x with always with 0.0 so all the labels were overlapping each other. see the line `CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0 * i,0.0, scrollView1.frame.size.width, scrollView1.frame.size.height);` as you multiplying i with 0.0

Comment: just change the line to this CGRect frame = CGRectMake(5.0+(i*768.0), 0.0, scrollView1.frame.size.width, scrollView1.frame.size.height);

Comment: well its working but not really the way i wanted.. now i'll have to set textlabel style font color frame everything manually. isn't there any simple way to just make it visible with changing content? when rest of the things are set by storyboard.

Comment: hum you mean the background of label also changes with according to the color of content of scrollview content, right?

Comment: and if this is what you want, then sorry but i don't know any way other then coding it manually. but you can put it as the new question may be some one know something